# How to calculate checkbox that been check in datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys i got some question about datagridview checkbox.. the thing is that i want to calculate the checkbox that have been checked in datagridview and show it to user how many that have been check but it show less than one that i checked

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim kk As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim checkselect As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells("chkCheck").Value)
        If checkselect = 1 Then
            kk += 1
        End If
    Next
    lblSelect.Text = kk
End Sub
```

This is the coding that i want to calculate and show to user..can anyone find my mistake

[image]

This how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a EndEdit before

```
 DataGridView1.EndEdit()
 Dim kk As Integer = 0
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
```